# while loop returing last loop repeating each time

Tags: php, android, json, while-loop

I am trying to make a messaging system in PHP in a dinky little app I'm making in android. I've gotten it mostly sorted out but there Is 1 problem I cant seem to fix. in my messaging system I want to display all the conversations the user has with other users along with the last text sent or received like on most messaging systems. the problem I am having is that the PHP script I made to get and displays all the conversation displays the last message for one user over and over again, for all the conversation the user has ongoing. see below

[image: app in practice]

this is what my message table looks like, note it is supposed to get and display only the last text sent or recived, it does this but it only for 1 user but it displays it for both. if I had 3 or more texts from or to peter it would look the same but if I messaged another user it would display 3 texts

[image]

here is my code.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basicbook;charset=utf8mb4", 'root', '', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);

require_once "basicbookconfig.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $f = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonobj = stripslashes($f);
    $obj = json_decode($jsonobj);

    $email = $obj[0];

//    step 1 get id from email


    $sql0 = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE email = ?";
    $stmt0 = $conn->prepare($sql0);
    $stmt0->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt0->execute();
    $stmt0->store_result();
    if($stmt0->num_rows == 1) {
        $stmt0->bind_result($id);
        $stmt0->fetch();

//        step 2 get chats off all people with that id

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `person1`, `person2` FROM `chats` WHERE `person1` = ? or `person2` = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$id,$id]);
        $return22 = array();


        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $person1 = $row["person1"];
            $person2 = $row["person2"];

//            echo $person1;
//            echo $person2;
//            echo "here";
//            I expect it to do this twice


            $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `message_id`, `user_to`, `user_from`, `message`  FROM `messages` WHERE `user_to` = ? or ? and `user_from` = ? or ? ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 1");
            $stmt2->execute([$person1,$person2, $person1,$person2]);

            while ($results = $stmt2->fetch()) {

                $message_id = $results["message_id"];
                $user_to = $results["user_to"];
                $user_from = $results["user_from"];
                $message = $results["message"];

                if ($user_to == $id) {
                    $friend = $user_from;
                } elseif ($user_from == $id) {
                    $friend = $user_to;
                } else {
                echo "there is a problem1";
                }

                $sql3 = "SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?";
                $stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql3);
                $stmt3->bind_param("s", $friend);
                $stmt3->execute();
                $stmt3->store_result();
                $stmt3->bind_result($name);
                $stmt3->fetch();

                $return22[] =  array('message_id'=>$message_id, 'otherperson'=>$name, 'message'=>$message);

            }
            $b = array("my_messages" => $return22);

        }
        echo json_encode($b);

    }
}
```

I have been trying varius fixes for a while now. anyways I hope it makes sense what I am trying to do. thank you and have a nice day, if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Errr, You connect using PDO with the connection in `$pdo` and then use `MYSQLI_`  calls using `$conn` as the connection? I dont think so!! Are you sure this code is running?? And then you switch back to PDO. ???????????????????

Comment: yes, it is running. I have a database connection right in the code, it references another file. I have other code that uses both that works just fine. the problem is with the while loop. could you please provide help with that

Comment: There are So many reason why using both extensions in the same code is a bad idea

Comment: I dont think the query containing `WHERE user_to = ? or ? and user_from = ? or ?` will do what you think. The `or ? ` wont do what you think, and there needs to be some brackets whenever you use AND and OR on the same WHERE Clause. `WHERE (user_to = ? or user_to = ? ) and (user_from = ? or user_from = ?)`

Comment: I have done dry runs of the query in phpmyadmin . It does what I want it to. it gets the last chat between the 2 users in question.  I tried it with the brackets just in case and It got me the same result.

Comment: Please humour me and execute this query in phpMyAdmin `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_to = 99;` I would expect based on the 3 rows you show us you will get no results then execute this query `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_to = 99 OR 55;` Note, now because of the `OR 55` you get all the rows in your table even though you have no rows where `user_to` is 55

Comment: Sorry, got my AND's and OR's muddled up in the comment I deleted

Comment: wow, thanks, man, I did what you said and I made a video showing it if you want.  you were right, it was my SQL query. It worked for other simpler problems that I was having just fine but I guess I was wrong. well thanks. I fixed it with the following command. `WHERE (user_to = ? or user_to = ?) and (user_from = ? or user_from = ?)` would there be any problems with this, it seems to work

Comment: I Dont think so